# Tmux on Windows WSL: unable to start a new pane at current directory

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## Trouble:

With identical settings, and a safety check command, firing shortcuts to create new panes in Tmux on WSL only get me new panes started at home dir. Settings as well demonstrations go as below:
[image]

*Clarification*: I am sourcing the same `_tmux_settings` script on another Linux machine, and panes are splitting nicely: right at where they should have been, the "pwd" of where I am firing it.

- My Windows OS is: `17134.376`
- My WSL verion is: `Linux LL-PC 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #345-Microsoft Wed Sep 19 17:47:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

### Question:

How may I start new panes at current working directory, instead of being sent back to home directory? It is confusing as the return value from `tmux display ...` command does show that `#{pane_current_path}` is evaluated correctly.

#### References:

- [This Github Issue for WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1063) Mentioned that things should go well if `tmux display -p '#{pane_current_path}'` is working, then new panes should strat normally.
- [This Github issue for Tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/762) seems more relevant, but it is unclear what to do when `tmux display` is showing paths as they should have been.

Comment: Thank you for the ref. As tested `$PWD` also does not help. (I have tried to set it up in `~/.tmux.conf`, and new panes are still all created at home directory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue! In my case it was caused by a `cd ~` in my .bashrc.

Comment: I asked the original question, and this was exactly the case ==> took me quite a good number of months to figure this "feature/bug". Abandoning my original answer and selecting this post as the shorter solution. (PS: @someone who downvoted, please rever it. Thx.)

Answer (score 1):

## User's own fault

I have to confess that `tmux` has been doing its job exactly as prescribed. It was a line of four characters (`cd ~`) that brought up the alleged trouble. I would like to endorse the [great answer](https://superuser.com/a/1414911/361600) above :)

What had happened could be explained as the following:

- My original `tmux` settings had a line of `cd ~` somewhere in `~/.tmux.conf`;
- Per the new installation, I wiped out the entire partition on the hard drive, and thus got rid of the `cd ~` setting.
- This is where `(-1)*(-1) = +1` ==> two user mistakes that fixed the trouble :) [@Native English speaker, please comment the proper expression. Thx!]

---

## TL;DR

I keep the original "answer" as below. Nothing was added or deleted. Keeping everything together in case someone runs into the same `cd ~` trouble again. (Also, dear the administrator, please do not delete this post. I have spent hours trying to fix such trouble, and I do not want other people to suffer from the loss of such hours in their lives.)

### An answer that is not a real answer

Well, after the following two *concrete* steps, the symptom I reported vanished.

- Reinstall the Windows 10 OS, and
- Reinstall the WSL system

By the way, I have also replaced the entire set of hardware :) ***In particular,*** I did not change anything in my `~/.tmux.conf`, nor any WSL configuration files. (For WSL specifically, I did not touch anything in `/etc/wsl.conf`.)

### Specs and screenshot (problem fixed)

Here goes the current versions of Windows & WSL, with another screenshot showing that the original problem has been resolved.

- Windows OS Build: `17134.376`.
- WSL version: `Linux PC 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #345-Microsoft Wed Sep 19 17:47:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

[image]